# How to Hook up M-Audio 2x2 Mtrack with Yamaha MG10XU MIxer for recording via laptop

Tags: recording

I want to connect an M-Audio M Track 2x2M audio interface to a Yamaha MG 10 XU analog mixer, and record live using Cubase LE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The M track only has two inputs, so you can only record a stereo signal if you are recording all channels live.  You would send from the Yamaha mixer out of the Stereo Out section, either using the quarter inch output to the instrument in on the M audio, or the XLR outs to the mic/line inputs.  The XLR send is the better choice.

You will have to have the mix that you want set up from the mixer, so you should check the mix from the main outs of the M Track with headphones.